# HTML align center with respect to the element, not the webpage layout

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align:left;">
A B C D E F G 
</div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
D
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What should I do if I want the second element D is right below (centered) A B C D E F G?
My way, the D is at the center of the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put both of them inside an inline-block element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display:inline-block">
<div style="text-align:left;">
A B C D E F G 
</div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
D
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A second solution: You can wrap a container element around those divs and apply `display: inline-flex`, `flex-direction: column;` and `align-items: center;` to that container.

`display: inline-flex`, limits the width of the container to the contents, `flex-direction: column;` places the children *below* each other and and `align-items: center;` centers the contents inside the children elements. You won't need the inline text-alignments in this case.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      A B C D E F G
    </div>
    <div>
      D
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```